# How to randomly assign values row-wise in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

My google-fu has failed me!
I have a 10x10 numpy array initialized to `0` as follows:

```
arr2d = np.zeros((10,10))
```

For each row in `arr2d`, I want to assign 3 random columns to `1`. I am able to do it using a loop as follows:

```
for row in arr2d:
    rand_cols = np.random.randint(0,9,3)
    row[rand_cols] = 1
```

**output:**

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Is there a way to exploit numpy or array indexing/slicing to achieve the same result in a more pythonic/elegant way (preferably in 1 or 2 lines of code)?

Comment: Did you notice that one of your rows has only two `1`s?  That can happen if `randint(0, 9, 3)` generates a sample with a repeated value.   Is that what you want?

Comment: So, did any of the solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the `arr2d` initialized with `arr2d = np.zeros((10,10))`, you can use a vectorized approach with a `two-liner` like so -

```
# Generate random unique 3 column indices for 10 rows
idx = np.random.rand(10,10).argsort(1)[:,:3]

# Assign them into initialized array
arr2d[np.arange(10)[:,None],idx] = 1
```

Or cramp in everything for a one-liner if you like it that way -

```
arr2d[np.arange(10)[:,None],np.random.rand(10,10).argsort(1)[:,:3]] = 1
```

Sample run -

```
In [11]: arr2d = np.zeros((10,10))  # Initialize array

In [12]: idx = np.random.rand(10,10).argsort(1)[:,:3]

In [13]: arr2d[np.arange(10)[:,None],idx] = 1

In [14]: arr2d # Verify by manual inspection
Out[14]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])

In [15]: arr2d.sum(1) # Verify by counting ones in each row
Out[15]: array([ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.])
```

Note : If you are looking for performance, I would suggest going with a `np.argpartition` based approach as listed in [`this other post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35416369/3293881).

Comment: Really cool. There's a whole lot of cleverness packed into these two lines of code.

Comment: @zarak The original idea came from this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29156976/3293881. The speedups against a loopy approach are listed here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31958263/3293881

Answer (score 1):

Use answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505651/non-repetitive-random-number-in-numpy) to generate non-repeating random numbers. You can use `random.sample` from Python's `random` module, or `np.random.choice`.

So, just a small modification to your code:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> for row in arr2d:
...     rand_cols = np.random.choice(range(10), 3, replace=False)
...     # Or the python standard lib alternative (use `import random`)
...     # rand_cols = random.sample(range(10), 3)
...     row[rand_cols] = 1
...
>>> arr2d
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

I don't think you can really leverage column slicing here to *set* values to 1, unless you're generating the randomized array from scratch. This is because your column indices are random *for each row*. You're better off leaving it in the form of a loop for readability.

Comment: FYI: You can generate non-repeating random numbers using `numpy.random.choice(10, size=3, replace=False)`.  This is described in one of the answers to the question that you linked.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I did notice, but I didn't include it because it was the second result. I'll add it as an alternative. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, in retrospect, it's probably better to just use `np.random` in order to avoid having two very similar imports, which could get pretty confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how good this would be in terms of performance, but it's fairly concise.

```
arr2d[:, :3] = 1
map(np.random.shuffle, arr2d)
```

Comment: That picks the same columns for every row.